# Fastest way of doing field comparisons in the same table with large amounts of data in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, large-data

I am recieving information from a csv file from one department to compare with the same inforation in a different department to check for discrepencies (About 3/4 of a million rows of data with 44 columns in each row). After I have the data in a table, I have a program that will take the data and send reports based on a HQ. I feel like the way I am going about this is not the most efficient. I am using oracle for this comparison.

Here is what I have:

- I have a vb.net program that parses the data and inserts it into an extract table
- I run a procedure to do a full outer join on the two tables into a new table with the fields in one department prefixed with '_c'
- I run another procedure to compare the old/new data and update 2 different tables with detail and summary information. Here is code from inside the procedure:

  ```
  DECLARE 
    CURSOR Cur_Comp IS SELECT * FROM T.AEC_CIS_COMP;
  BEGIN 
  FOR compRow in Cur_Comp LOOP

      --If service pipe exists in CIS but not in FM and the service pipe has status of retired in CIS, ignore the variance
      If(compRow.pipe_num = '' AND cis_status_c = 'R')
          continue
      END IF

      --If there is not a summary record for this HQ in the table for this run, create one
      INSERT INTO t.AEC_CIS_SUM (HQ, RUN_DATE)
      SELECT compRow.HQ, to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT null FROM t.AEC_CIS_SUM WHERE HQ = compRow.HQ AND RUN_DATE = to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))

      -- Check fields and update the tables accordingly
      If (compRow.cis_loop <> compRow.cis_loop_c) Then
          --Insert information into the details table
          INSERT INTO T.AEC_CIS_DET( Fac_id, Pipe_Num, Hq, Address, AutoUpdatedFl, 
                                                DateTime, Changed_Field, CIS_Value, FM_Value)
          VALUES(compRow.Fac_ID, compRow.Pipe_Num, compRow.Hq, compRow.Street_Num || ' ' || compRow.Street_Name,
                 'Y', sysdate, 'Cis_Loop', compRow.cis_loop, compRow.cis_loop_c); 

          -- Update information into the summary table        
          UPDATE AEC_CIS_SUM                 
          SET cis_loop = cis_loop + 1
          WHERE Hq = compRow.Hq
            AND Run_Date = to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')               
      End If;       
  END LOOP;
  ```

  END;

Any suggestions of an easier way of doing this rather than an if statement for all 44 columns of the table? (This is run once a week if it matters)

Update: Just to clarify, there are 88 columns of data (44 of duplicates to compare with one suffixed with _c). One table lists each field in a row that is different so one row can mean 30+ records written in that table. The other table keeps tally of the number of discrepencies for each week.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I believe that your task can be implemented (and should be actually) with staight SQL. No fancy cursors, no loops, just selects, inserts and updates. I would start with unpivotting your source data (it is not clear if you have primary key to join two sets, I guess you do):

```
Col0_PK    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------------------
Row1_val   A       B       C       D
Row2_val   E       F       G       H
```

Above is your source data. Using [`UNPIVOT` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#sthref1226) we convert it to:

```
Col0_PK     Col_Name    Col_Value
------------------------------
Row1_val    Col1        A
Row1_val    Col2        B
Row1_val    Col3        C
Row1_val    Col4        D
Row2_val    Col1        E
Row2_val    Col2        F
Row2_val    Col3        G
Row2_val    Col4        H
```

I think you get the idea. Say we have table1 with one set of data and the same structured table2 with the second set of data. It is good idea to use index-organized tables.

Next step is comparing rows to each other and storing difference details. Something like:

```
insert into diff_details(some_service_info_columns_here)
 select some_service_info_columns_here_along_with_data_difference
  from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
     on t1.Col0_PK = t2.Col0_PK
    and t1.Col_name = t2.Col_name
    and nvl(t1.Col_value, 'Dummy1') <> nvl(t2.Col_value, 'Dummy2');
```

And on the last step we update difference summary table:

```
insert into diff_summary(summary_columns_here)
 select diff_row_id, count(*) as diff_count
  from diff_details
 group by diff_row_id;
```

It's just rough draft to show my approach, I'm sure there is much more details should be taken into account. To summarize I suggest two things:

1. `UNPIVOT` data
2. Use `SQL` statements instead of cursors

Comment: This is some great information, thank you. Would you still suggest going this route if there are conditions. If this field is different because the other doesnt exist, update this way, else update that way? Also one set of data is coming from a view not a table.

Comment: @TroyLoberger Sure, you can implement some logic in your update query. I.e. you can use `CASE` expression in select list to check for nullity or for specific values in your data. Regarding set of data coming from view I suggest to load it into intermediate table (you could do it along with unpivoting). SQL engine is much more effective in sorting, comparing and other processing of large sets of data whereas the main purpose of PL/SQL is implementing of structured procedural processing when logic becomes too complex to form one query.

Comment: I'm aware of being able to use case statements and such. I was just more worried about how complex it would get and the time it takes to load the 750,000 rows with 44 columns in each into an intermediate table and then pivoting it. I have the way I started earlier complete but Ill the pivoting a try and run some timed tests! Thanks again for the help, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

```
If(compRow.pipe_num = '' AND cis_status_c = 'R')
    continue
END IF
```

"cis_status_c" is not declared. Is it a variable or a column in AEC_CIS_COMP?
In case it is a column, just put the condition into the cursor, i.e. `SELECT * FROM T.AEC_CIS_COMP WHERE not (compRow.pipe_num = '' AND cis_status_c = 'R')`

```
to_date(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

That's nonsense, you convert a date into a date, simply use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

Anyway, I think you can use three single statements instead of a cursor:

```
INSERT INTO t.AEC_CIS_SUM (HQ, RUN_DATE)
SELECT comp.HQ, trunc(sysdate)
from AEC_CIS_COMP comp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT null FROM t.AEC_CIS_SUM WHERE HQ = comp.HQ AND RUN_DATE = trunc(sysdate));


INSERT INTO T.AEC_CIS_DET( Fac_id, Pipe_Num, Hq, Address, AutoUpdatedFl, DateTime, Changed_Field, CIS_Value, FM_Value)
select comp.Fac_ID, comp.Pipe_Num, comp.Hq, comp.Street_Num || ' ' || comp.Street_Name, 'Y', sysdate, 'Cis_Loop', comp.cis_loop, comp.cis_loop_c
from T.AEC_CIS_COMP comp
where comp.cis_loop <> comp.cis_loop_c;

UPDATE AEC_CIS_SUM                 
SET cis_loop = cis_loop + 1
WHERE Hq IN (Select Hq from T.AEC_CIS_COMP)
  AND trunc(Run_Date) = trunc(sysdate);
```

They are not tested but they should give you a hint how to do it.

Comment: Yea the cis_status_c i caught on. I was more hoping to find an easier way or more proficient way to code it than to fix what is there. (It was more of just a rough draft of how im going to code). And I did not know abou the trunc(sysdate), that is awesome, thank you for the heads up on that! But to your suggestion, I agree with the first 1. But the last 2 wouldnt work this way. I only have one field on there for ex. there are 44 different fields to compare and updating these tables based on each field not just once a row.

Comment: You asked how to make the operation faster. Again, try to get rid of explicit cursor and the loop. Try to do as much as possible in simple DML statements. The [INSERT ALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2079970) or the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) could be usefull.